# Gracefully handle Firebase downtime

Tags: firebase

Does [this hook](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-bower/blob/master/firebase-debug.js#L2938) work during such [downtimes](https://twitter.com/FirebaseStatus/status/565782658509062145)? (although thats in firebase-debug.js)

Or more generally, is there a mechanism to detect such conditions, so that the app can handle it gracefully.

Comment: Did you check the [offline capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html)? Specifically, it sounds like you may want `.info/connected`

Comment: Yes, I use that, and it does not seem to trigger during that downtime.